# setSupportActionBar on fragment class Android

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar

I want to add a toolbar for my class which handles the communication between the fragments.

```
public class FragmentClass extends Activity implements Communicator{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.content2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.playerToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

[image]

As ypu can see Im getting error on setSupportActionbar, when i hover over it I get `"cannot resolve method 'setSupportActionbar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)'"`

Comment: You shouldn't name a class with the word Fragment and have it extend an Activity. That just confuses people. Also the Class suffix is quite redundant.

Comment: Alternatively, maybe you should extend Fragment, but you'd still have the same problem of that method not being defined because you can only call that on an AppCompatActivity class

Comment: Did my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680718/setsupportactionbar-on-fragment-class-android/36680749#36680749) solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your activity should extend `AppCompactActivity`:

```
public class FragmentClass extends AppCompactActivity implements Communicator{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.content2);
       Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

And also `Toolbar` should be imported from `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` not from `android.widget.Toolbar`

On a different note: Your activity's name shouldn't be `FragmentClass` creates confusion because it is not extending `Fragment`. It should be something like `MainActivity`

Answer (score 1):

Use AppcomactActivity with Appcomacttheme.

Try with new Basic Activity in android studio and  code will be added automatically like AppTheme and AppCompatActivity, Toolbar and FloatingActionButton.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```